# I am getting an error when I try to update records in my access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand, executenonquery

I have a small program that connects to an access database, and what I am trying to do is update(edit) a selected record via an edit form. When I execute my code, I get this error:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled
  Message=Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '5346 S. Eubank blvd'.
  Source=Microsoft Access Database Engine
  ErrorCode=-2147217900
```

Needless to say, it is for the Address field..

Here is my code block:

```
private void saveChangeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Customer.SetCustID(Convert.ToInt32(editIdTB.Text));
    Customer.SetFirstName(editFirstNameTB.Text);
    Customer.SetLastName(editFirstNameTB.Text);
    Customer.SetAddress(editAddressTB.Text);
    Customer.SetPhoneNum(editPhoneTB.Text);
    Customer.SetEmail(editEmailTB.Text);

    using (OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        connect.Open();

        cmd.Connection = connect;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Customers SET [Customer ID]=" + Customer.GetCustId() +
            ", [First Name]=" + Customer.GetFirstName() +
            ", [Last Name]=" + Customer.GetLastName() +
            ", [Address]=" + Customer.GetAddress() +
            ", [Phone Number]=" + Customer.GetPhoneNum() +
            ", [Email Address]=" + Customer.GetEmailAddress() + 
            ", WHERE [Customer ID]=" + editIdTB.Text + "";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connect.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Changes made successfully!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Should there be a comma before the WHERE? Do you allow the user to change the Customer ID? Seems like you wouldn't want to do so, or use a different primary key if so. If you simplify the query to just update address and skip the rest do you still get the same error?

Comment: Echo your cmd.CommandText to the page or a log file so you can see what you are trying to execute.

Comment: I did just the address and go this error:

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled
  Message=Syntax error in string in query expression ''5346 S. Eubank blvd WHERE [Customer ID]=3'.
  Source=Microsoft Access Database Engine
  ErrorCode=-2147217900
  StackTrace:
       at

Comment: StackTrace:
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)

Comment: It's way too long for me to even try and post in these stupid boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Customers SET [First Name]='" + Customer.GetFirstName() +
            "', [Last Name]='" + Customer.GetLastName() +
            "', [Address]='" + Customer.GetAddress() +
            "', [Phone Number]='" + Customer.GetPhoneNum() +
            "', [Email Address]='" + Customer.GetEmailAddress() + 
            "' WHERE [Customer ID]=" + editIdTB.Text;
```

Comment: That worked! I see you got rid of the excess quotes at the end, and dropped the Customer ID! Excellent! Thank you!

Comment: And quotes around the values... didn't realize that was an issue as well!

Comment: You'll probably want to search and replace single quotes with 2 single quotes in any of these values or your SQL statement will break again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have is the comma before WHERE.  Try remove that and give it a try.

It would be easier to diagnostics if you can capture the exact sql your executing, and try to run it in a query browser.

Also, I recommend you to use string.format when you are constructing the sql.  For a better solution, try LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework.

Comment: Well, I changed it to no avail... even added single quotes around all the strings and put all of my values inside parentheses, which didn't help... I will try running it in a browser though, that is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put quotes around the values.  that should solve the main problem here.

however, you have a pretty enormous security flaw here.  google "sql injection" and you'll see that a bad guy can seriously ruin your week by putting malicious text into the editIfTB textbox

Comment: This is just a personal project, and won't contain any sensitive data. But when I create more substantial programs, I certainly will take up your advice. Never the less, I'll look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from security vulnernability, constructing queries this way will still have a stability problem. As soon as one of your data fields includes an apostrophe, the SQL will break again (e.g. surname O'Neill). Best practice is to supply all data values via parameters; it avoids the need to concatenate in all those single-quotes/apostrophes, won't be sensitive to data values, and won't have a security vulnerability.