# insert into error using access + asp.net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

im tring to insert new data to an Access table.
the table has 4 parameters. the first one is an autonumber.
this is my code:

```
public void InsertToDB(int stationId, DateTime dateTime, double temperture)
{

    connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Database1.accdb";

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connect;
    cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into TempDate (StationID,DateTime,Temper)" + "Values(@ID,@dateTime,@temper)";

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = stationId;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateTime", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateTime;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@temper", OleDbType.Double).Value = temperture;

    connect.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();          //At this line exception is generating
    connect.Close();


}// insert to db
```

im getting this error:

ErrorCode=-2147217900

Comment: Maybe just put that errorcode to google search?? Already gives so many results how to fix it, for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898551/i-am-getting-an-error-when-i-try-to-update-records-in-my-access-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a space before Values. You can put it in one string, no need to concatenate them. Also, as Gord said - DateTime is a reserved word - so put it in brackets. For example:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into TempDate (StationID,[DateTime],Temper) Values (@ID,@dateTime,@temper)";
```

Answer (score 0):

`DATETIME` is apparently a reserved word so you need to enclose it in square brackets:

```csharp
cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into TempDate (StationID,[DateTime],Temper)" + ...
```